# Конкатенация строк из файлов в случайном порядке

Tags: c#

Есть 2 *.txt* файла, и в каждом из них есть строки. Как рандомно выбрать строки из первого и второго файлов и сложить их вместе? Может быть, нужно каждый *.txt* через массив `foreach`?

P.S. и с `условием пока не ...`.
P.P.S. Количество строк в обоих файлах одинаковое: 100 штук.

Comment: По описанию не понятно, что нужно сделать. Выбрать по одной рандомной строке из каждого файла и склеить их в новую строку или что-то другое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкатенация строк из файлов в случайном порядке ровно за N итераций:

```
List<string> firstLines = File.ReadLines("first.txt").ToList();
List<string> secondLines = File.ReadLines("second.txt").ToList();
var result = new List<string>();
Random random = new Random();
while (firstLines.Any() && secondLines.Any())
{
    int firstIndex = random.Next(0, firstLines.Count);
    int secondIndex = random.Next(0, secondLines.Count);
    result.Add(firstLines[firstIndex] + secondLines[secondIndex]);
    firstLines.RemoveAt(firstIndex);
    secondLines.RemoveAt(secondIndex);
}
result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Генерация на каждой итерации случайного числа от 0 до N и проверка на то, было ли такое число раньше, чреваты ощутимым увеличением количества итераций. Для 100 элементов это приводит, в среднем, к 1000 итераций.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  public class Program
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
      // Последовательно.
      using (var file1 = new StreamReader("1.txt"))
      {
        using (StreamReader file2 = new StreamReader("2.txt"))
        {
          string lineFrom1File, lineFrom2File;
          while ((lineFrom1File = file1.ReadLine()) != null && (lineFrom2File = file2.ReadLine()) != null)
          {
            Console.WriteLine(lineFrom1File + lineFrom2File);
          }
        }
      }

      // Последовательно 2.
      var usedLines = new HashSet<int>();
      var linesFromFile1 = File.ReadLines("1.txt"); // or ReadAllLines
      var linesFromFile2 = File.ReadLines("2.txt"); // or ReadAllLines

      foreach (var newLine in linesFromFile1.Zip(linesFromFile2, (s1, s2) => s1 + s2))
        Console.WriteLine(newLine);

      // Случайным образом.
      Console.WriteLine();
      var userLines = new HashSet<int>();
      var allLinesFromFile1 = File.ReadAllLines("1.txt");
      var allLinesFromFile2 = File.ReadAllLines("2.txt");
      var rnd = new Random();
      while (usedLines.Count <= allLinesFromFile1.Length)
      {
        var randLineNumber = rnd.Next(0, allLinesFromFile1.Length);
        if (usedLines.Contains(randLineNumber))
          continue;
        usedLines.Add(randLineNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(allLinesFromFile1[randLineNumber] + allLinesFromFile2[randLineNumber]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: он просто показывает простой перебор подряд всех строк, а мне нужно рандомные строки подряд!

Comment: @glonval, окей, в чем проблема модифицировать мой код для решения это задачи?

Comment: проблема в том что я не знаю как это сделать, (офф: знал бы, ничего тут не спрашивал бы)

Comment: @glonval, Вы что то пробовали сделать?